# How can I minify my index.php using grunt?

Tags: php, html, optimization, gruntjs, minify

> **I want to achieve this using grunt**

---

## Goal

- My main goal is to minify my index.php before placing them on my production server.
- It's simple if I have 1 single `index.html`, but I don't.
- Instead I have an **`index.php`** full with other `.php` files.
- Each `<?php ?>` section is a block of HTML code.

---

## index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php include '2015/layouts/ie.php'; ?>

<head>
  <?php include '2015/layouts/meta.php'; ?>
  <title>Title</title>
  <?php include '2015/layouts/link.php'; ?>
  <?php include '2015/layouts/style.php'; ?>
  <?php include '2015/layouts/ie9.php'; ?>
</head>


<body >

  <span id="web">
    <?php include '2015/layouts/nav-bar.php'; ?>
    <?php include '2015/layouts/welcome-sign.php'; ?>
    <?php include '2015/layouts/profile.php'; ?>
    <?php include '2015/layouts/skill.php'; ?>
    <?php include '2015/layouts/education.php'; ?>
    <?php include '2015/layouts/experience.php'; ?>
    <?php include '2015/layouts/portfolio.php'; ?>
    <?php include '2015/layouts/contact.php'; ?>
    <?php include '2015/layouts/script.php'; ?>
  </span>

  <span id="print" style="display: none;" ><img src="2015/img/image.png" width="90%"></span>

</body>


</html>
```

---

## Lastly

I'm wondering what is the most efficient way to concatenate all my .php files into one php file, and minify it.

I prefer to achieve this using grunt, but if someone might have other suggestion on a better solution please feel free to suggest me.

Comment: Please don't mark my post, he is not using grunt. I am.

Comment: possible for you to write the php output into a template and minify that?

Comment: Do you mind teach me how to do that by answer it ?

Comment: Hello you can use php function ob_start() like 
`ob_start();

        include 'index.php';

        file_put_contents('index.html', ob_get_clean());`
and then use index.html to minify

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Where should I put that block of code ?

Comment: I've tried it : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193678/minify-index-php)

Comment: create php file with code above, then add exec task to grunt like http://grunt-tasks.com/grunt-exec/ where call php file which create index.html file

Comment: Sound like a good plan. I will try that now. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: If you downvote me, can you please explain why so I can I learn from it ?

Comment: @dyachenko : Base on your comment, it sound like you know what you're doing. Do you mind answer it base on your comment ? I'll make sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to create html file from php you can use PHP `ob_start()`  function.
So you create PHP file php2html.php

**php2html.php**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include 'index.php'; 
    file_put_contents('index.html', ob_get_clean());
```

then create **exec** task in GRUNT to call php2html.php script (read more about exec task https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec
)

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');

    grunt.initConfig({
        exec: {
            php2html: {
                cmd: 'php php2html.php'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['exec:php2html']);
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-exec": "~0.4.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause"
}
```

and at the last minify created index.html

Comment: Thanks for sparing your knowledge. Cheers.

Comment: Now that you're showing as what I need to do in php, can you add a little but more showing, how would we accomplish this in grunt configuration. That'll be great if you can update your answer with that.

Comment: Thank you very much for update your answer base on my request, I saw it. Hey ! What do you think about my current answer ? You like it ?

Answer (score 3):

## I accomplished this in 2 simple  steps:

- concat all the php file into 1 long php file
- minify that long php file

---

## Step1

using : **grunt-contrib-concat**

```
concat: {

    php: {

        src: [

            '2015/layouts/ie.php',
            '2015/layouts/meta.php',
            '2015/layouts/link.php',
            '2015/layouts/style.php',
            '2015/layouts/ie9.php',
            '2015/layouts/nav-bar.php',
            '2015/layouts/welcome-sign.php',
            '2015/layouts/profile.php',
            '2015/layouts/skill.php',
            '2015/layouts/education.php',
            '2015/layouts/experience.php',
            '2015/layouts/portfolio.php',
            '2015/layouts/contact.php',
            '2015/layouts/script.php'

        ],

        dest: 'dist/php/concat.php'

    }
}
```

---

## Step2

using :  **grunt-contrib-htmlmin**

```
htmlmin: {

    dist: {
        options: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true
        },

        tasks: ['clean:php'],
        files: {
            'index.php': 'dist/php/concat.php',
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Final `grunt.initConfig()` should look like

```
grunt.initConfig({

        concat: {

            php: {

                src: [

                    '2015/layouts/ie.php',
                    '2015/layouts/meta.php',
                    '2015/layouts/link.php',
                    '2015/layouts/style.php',
                    '2015/layouts/ie9.php',
                    '2015/layouts/nav-bar.php',
                    '2015/layouts/welcome-sign.php',
                    '2015/layouts/profile.php',
                    '2015/layouts/skill.php',
                    '2015/layouts/education.php',
                    '2015/layouts/experience.php',
                    '2015/layouts/portfolio.php',
                    '2015/layouts/contact.php',
                    '2015/layouts/script.php'

                ],

                dest: 'dist/php/concat.php'

            }
        },

htmlmin: {

    dist: {
        options: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true
        },

        tasks: ['clean:php'],
        files: {
            'index.php': 'dist/php/concat.php',
        }
    }
},

    });


    // Load NPM Tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');

    // Default
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat','htmlmin']);

};
```

---

## Result

It will not be fun, If I don't show you guys the result. Here is it.

[image]