# Minify index.php

Tags: php, html, minify

## Situation

I'm struggling trying to minify my index.php file

---

## I've tried

Here is what's in my : `index.php`

```
<?php include 'master.php'; ?>

<?php

function htmlmin($buffer)

{
    $search = array( '/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s' );
    $replace = array('>','<','\\1');

    if (preg_match("/\<html/i",$buffer) == 1 && preg_match("/\<\/html\>/i", $buffer) == 1) {
        $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
    }

    return $buffer;
}

ob_start("htmlmin");

?>
```

---

When I do `view page source`, I still see my html output is not minify.
I know that I did something wrong, but I'm not sure what it is.

Did I forget to do something ? Am I on the right track ?
Can someone please give me hint ?

Comment: Maybe you look into that link: [minify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225351/how-to-minify-php-page-html-output)

Comment: @bub :  Thanks, but I did take a look in that link already, and I still couldn't get it to work. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Well the only thing I suggest is: Do not do HTML using regular expressions!!!

Comment: I totally agree with you. The reason why I tried it that way because I don't what else to do. Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

## I solved this

by using one of the **[grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)** task: **[grunt-contrib-htmlmin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-htmlmin)**

---

## Install

you may install this plugin with this command:

`npm install grunt-contrib-htmlmin --save-dev`

Once the plugin has been installed, add this to your **Gruntfile**

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');`

---

## Setting

```
htmlmin: {

    dist: {
        files: {
            'index.php': 'index.php',
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Final File

```
grunt.initConfig({
    
        htmlmin: {

            dist: {
                files: {
                    'index.php': 'index.php',
                }
            }
        }

    });


    // Load NPM Tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');

    // Default Setting
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['htmlmin']);

};
```

---

## Execute

Just run `grunt` on your terminal, the index.php will be minified.

---

## Test/Result

It will not be fun, If I don't show you guys the result. Here is it.

[image]